# How are C structures & offsets stored in memory by linker?

Tags: c, linker

I'm interested in systems programming, and want to see how structs are implemented in assembly, and how they are linked. 
I've written three short `.c` codes, with same named structs but in different files and compiled and linked together, but I can't understand the output. 
I believed that the struct is just a contiguous block of memory in assembly, in the data segment. But, I can't access the values after the first int data, either by using pointers or by having each function use its corresponding files' offsets. Can someone explain the output?

I tried to change data types, implement chars to avoid padding or endian problems. I tried using a `char*` pointer to print the entire structure, which surprisingly gives me weird values (not random, since they are the same in every execution)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S1 
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
    int i4;
    int i5;
    int i6;
};

int main()
{
    struct S1 s;
    s.i1 = 5;
    s.i2 = 10;
    s.i3 = 15;
    s.i4 = 16;

    func1(s);        //Implicit calls, no declarations needed
                     // because linker will know where to find defs
    func2(s);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S1
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    float i3;
};


void func1(struct S1 s)
{
    printf("In func1 : %d %d   %f %lu\n", s.i1, s.i2, s.i3, sizeof(s));
};
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S3
{
    double i1;
    int i2;
};

void func2(struct S3 s)
{
    printf("In func2 : %lf %d %lu \n", s.i1, s.i2, sizeof(s));
};
```

I'm getting outputs:

> In func1 : 1 0   0.000000 12
>
> In func2 : 0.000000 1 16

I expected the values to be printed

Comment: Your code won't compile for `func2`because the parameter is `S3`, you are giving `S1`

Comment: Actually `func1(s);` in main will assume a function definition of `int func1(int)` in older versions of C upto and including C89 and C90. Since C99 the implicit function declaration is not allowed.

Comment: You don't want to use implicit function declarations. Compile with warnings enabled and consider all warnings containing the word "implicit" as errors. Google "c implicit declaration of function" for more information

Comment: @RoQuOTriX it does compile, even with the wrong arguments, because it's the linker's job to link definitions within different files. I ran it and got an output, but it's not what I expected. Please understand that I'm aware of the wrong parameter, and I want it to be there, because I'm trying to understand how it gets implemented in lower levels

Comment: @Jabberwocky Can you please explain why implicit calls are bad in my case? I know its not conventional, but would that cause the unexpected output?

Comment: There is no such thing as "implicit calls". Just "implicit function declarations". Basically the function expects an `int` but you provide a `struct`. Implicit function declarations are dangerous for exactly that reason. Look at the generated assembly output if you want to understand what happens under the hood.

Comment: Calls to implicitly declared functions are bad in general, but worse in this case because you are calling the functions with mismatched parameters. Can you say _undefined behavior_?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Okay, I understand what you mean. But if I do `void func1(struct S1 s);
void func2(struct S3 s); ` then I can't pass 's' into func2. And that defeats my purpose. Even if I do  `void func1(struct S1 s);
void func2(struct S1 s); ` I still get the same unexpected output

Comment: You probably want to use `void` pointers. But anyway the function needs to know what type it actually receives. You should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. Read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You also need to tell us _what_ output you're expecting. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry for not making it clearer. i'm trying to learn how functions use struct offsets in assembly, since I learnt that all struct members are sequentially allocated and translated into offsets in asm. So if I pass a different struct i.e. S1 into a func that expects some other struct S3, I should be able to get the values of S1 with the offsets of S3. This demo code is only for my understanding. All I need is someone who can just explain the output.

Comment: First, state the compiler version you are using. the switches you are using to compile, and the system(s) you are building and executing on. Second, if you want to explore how the compiler passes structures to functions and how they are reinterpreted/misinterpreted when you use mismatching types between the calls and the definitions, then it would be better to dump the structure contents as bytes (using character pointers) rather than a mishmash of other types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Using gcc latest version, by `gcc file1.c file2.c file3.c` and nothing else, running it on Intel i5. Already tried printing values using a char pointer but it doesn't give correct results even at the first integer, where I expected 5, but it gives 1. I'm aware about the little endian layout and floating representations, and still the output is unexpected

Comment: Additionally, you should use a compiler switch to generate assembly language and then post that. The assembly language will reveal some of how the compiler handles structures. For example, trying it with Apple Clang for x86_64, it looks like the structure is not passed as a single object but rather its components are passed as separate arguments. In particular, because `f1` has a `float` member in the structure, it appears the compiler expects it to be passed in an XMM register. But the caller does not see a `float` member and does not put anything in an XMM register.

Comment: So you are not studying how structures are laid out in memory but how they are passed in function calls.

Comment: what you are doing make no sense at all. You can't pass around wrong types and expect to get anything meaningful

Comment: @4386427: The events that transpire when unsupported declarations are made are the consequences of concrete things in the world and can be examined, studied, and explained.

Comment: @ChinmayGupta: Do not say “latest version”. Use a number. Use “gcc -v” to see the version information. Is it 9.2? Is the target x86_64-linux-gnu or something else?

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP writes "I expected the values to be printed" I just told OP that that can't be expected

Comment: @4386427: Re “I just told OP that that can't be expected”: That is not what your comment says.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is to me and to C the whole thing is UB

Comment: @4386427: And the OP is not asking what the C standard says or defines. The question asks about the linker, assembly, and operation of a compiler, not the specification of the C standard. There is no reason the operation of compilers and other tools ought to be a black box that you prohibit people from looking inside, insisting that they rely solely upon what the C standard says and never learning anything else about how things work. Learning how things work—how things are designee and are **made** to work—is valuable information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not saying anything shall be treated as a black box. Studying how such things are operating is fine. But doing the study on code that are a violation of the standard is a waste of time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very well put. Actually, I'm studying how languages like C are implemented in a lower level, and that's the reason I want to see what happens when I mess around with func parameters that are not primitive data types, but blocks of memory.

Comment: @4386427: No, it is not a waste of time. It can provide useful information on how compilers work. Studying code that does not have behavior defined by the C standard may not tell you about the C standard, but it can tell you about other things.

Comment: In fact, I just noticed, if the struct S1 has only i1 to i4 as members, the output is what I expected, i.e. 5, 10 and so on. But as soon as I have i5 and i6, the output has first two integers as 1 and 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As GCC 9.2 compiles your file with `main`](https://godbolt.org/z/8a8nkN), we see these instructions for the call to `func1`:

```
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rdi, rdx
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     eax, 0
    call    func1
```

Note that the compiler has loaded data into general registers—`rsi`, `rdi`, and so on. Compare this to [the instructions in `func1`](https://godbolt.org/z/ymOOG1):

```
    mov     rdx, rdi
    movd    eax, xmm0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rdx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
```

In particular, note the `movss` instruction. That is attempting to retrieve the `float i3` member from the `xmm0` register. But, as we have seen, the calling routine did not put anything in the `xmm0` register.

The compiler has a specification for how arguments are passed between routines. This is called an Application Binary Interface. (The ABI is shared by software intended to be compatible on a particular platform and is often recommended by the processor manufacturer.) For small structures, at least in this case, the compiler does not pass them by pointing to them in memory or reproducing their exact layout. Instead, the members are passed individually, as if they were separate arguments.

Because of this, your code is not studying how structures are laid out in memory. It is studying how structures are passed in function calls. And part of the answer is that members are sometimes passed individually, and where they are passed depends in part on their types. Because `main` is passing only integer data, it uses registers for integer arguments. Because `func1` is expecting some floating-point data, it looks in a register for that. The result is that `func1` never gets the data that is passed for `i3` and `i4`.

Comment: Great. Thank you! I guess this is what happens when the university curriculum teaches old technology, not accounting for the newer developments. Just one more thing, I get why the float parameter isn't correctly working, but shouldn't the integer get printed correctly?

Comment: @ChinmayGupta: Looking at the assembly, I would expect so. `main` passes all 16 bytes of `s` in `rdi` and `rsi`. Then `func1` saves `rdi` to the stack (in two steps, moving it to `rdx` and then to `[rbp-16]`—this is unoptimized code). Then it gets 32-bit pieces from the stack (in `mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]` and `mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]`) and passes those to `printf`. I would expect the values of `i1` and `i2` to survive that. But I do not have GCC installed and cannot run this easily. I have to suspect a mismatch between the code you posted in the question and other experiments you ran.

Answer (score 0):

While Eric's answer is good, I'd like to highlight one additional misunderstanding your question contains:

> ```
>     func1(s);        //Implicit calls, no declarations needed
> ```

The comment is incorrect. C **always requires declarations** of functions. It does allow you to declare it without a prototype, as:

```
void func1();
```

However, to call it, the promoted type of the arguments must match the actual type in the function's definition (even if that definition is in another translation unit). If it does not match, the behavior is undefined.